# Azure VM: using an RSA-HSM key to encrypt disk

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rsa, hsm

I have an RSA-HSM key generated from nCipher nShield Hardware Security Modules and I added it to my Azure Key Vault.

How is it possible to encrypt OS disk with that key? It seems Azure Disk Encryption (ADE)does only accept RSA keys, but not *-HSM:

[AKV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6uEd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to select a non-managed disk for my vm linked to a storage account, so i'm able to select my RSA-HSM key.